# How to know that I have another thread running apart from the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have a routine like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Some_Work));
    t.Start();
}
```

I need to put a condition so that, "If there is not already a thread running apart from the Main thread, start a new thread".

But how to test for whether a thread is running other than the Main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is of course to either store a reference to the existing thread, or just set a flag that you have a thread running.

You should also maintain that field (reference or flag) so that if the thread exits, it should unset that field so that the next "start request" starts a new one.

Easiest solution:

```
private volatile Thread _Thread;

...

if (_Thread == null)
{
    _Thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Some_Work));
    _Thread.Start();
}

private void Some_Work()
{
    try
    {
        // your thread code here
    }
    finally
    {
        _Thread = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's several other threads running in your .NET app before it even gets to `button1_Click`. For instance, the finalizer thread is always hanging around, and I think WinForms creates one or two for itself.

Do you need to know about other threads that you've created? If so, you should keep track of them yourself. If not: why?

**Edit:** are you looking to kick off some background processing on demand? Have you seen the `BackgroundWorker` component, which manages threads for you, together with their interaction with the user interface? Or direct programming against the thread pool, using `Delegate.BeginInvoke` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`?

Comment: In addition, Win32 creates and stops its own threads when it wants. E.g., showing a standard Open File dialog will create a couple of threads (and non-standard shell extensions may create even more); `QueueUserWorkItem()` may create additional threads for system thread pool, etc.

Comment: It answers your question. I'm still not sure why the information is useful: it's always going to return > 1 in a .NET app.

Comment: That's more like it, although not sure you need the 'IsAlive' check if you've got the '!= null' check.